# Variables inside methods

Tags: java, android

I have this method:

```
public String Nov2()
{
    String[] ops = new String[] {" + ", " - ", " * ", " / "};
    int i = rand.nextInt(4-0) + 0;
    String op1 = ops[i];

    int novnum1 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;

    int novnum2 = rand.nextInt(101-1) + 1;


    String novnum1str = Integer.toString(novnum1);

    String novnum2str = Integer.toString(novnum2);

    String nov2Exp = novnum1str + op1 + novnum2str + " = ";

    setContentView(R.layout.gameview);

    TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exp);

    display.setText(nov2Exp);

    return nov2Exp;
}
```

It returns the string nov2Exp, but what i want to do is actually work out the expression this method generates. novnum1 and novnum2 are my two terms and op1 supplies the operation, how could i make the result of the expression accesible to the rest of the program from this method?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me.  All the variables to which you refer are local; you are already accessing one of them, in what sense do you have a question on how to access the others?

Comment: Are you saying that you want this method to return an int (or possibly a float or double) instead of a String? You know what novnum1, novnum2, and op1 are. Why couldn't you just calculate the value with a switch block whose cases are the different operators?

Answer (score 2):

You could make a class called `Expression` or something similar, with a method that sets up the integers and the operation; then return an object of this class.  This class could have a `toString()` method that returns the object formatted in the way you've done it above.

Also, not quite related to your question; but in your snippet of code, you don't need `novnum1str` and `novnum2str` because the + operation automatically converts its arguments to strings, if one of them is string.  So you can just write `novnum1 + op1 + novnum2 + " = "`.

**Edit:**

So in more detail, the `Expression` class could have

- member variables for the two integers and the operator;
- a method that initialises them randomly, just like the first 5 lines of the method that you posted;
- a `toString()` method that formats these three and returns the String that you called `nov2Exp`;
- a `calculate()` method with a `switch` statement, that calculates the value of the expression.
- getters on all three member variables, so you can use them wherever they're needed.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that answer, what exactly are you proposing is done insde the Expression class?